# How to embed response from a method within an object in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, dictionary, collections

I have a object which looks as below.
The object will always have `3 error types` - `error1`, `error2`, `error3`

```
const data =
{
  "error1": {
    "7": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
        "Hostnames": "host123.com,hostabc.com,host33a.com..."
      }
    ],
    "8": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
        "Hostnames": "host223.com,host2c.com,host43a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1C",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ]
  },
  "error2": {
    "3": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2A"
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2B"
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ],
    "8": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2C"
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2D",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ]
  },
  "error3": {
    "1": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
        "Hostnames": "host1236.com"
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
        "Hostnames": "hostc3231.com"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have a function `fetchHostDetails(hostnames)` which takes `hostnames` as input and returns response as below:

```
[
  {
    "resType": "unknow data",
    "res": "missing data"
  },
  {
    "resType": "login failed",
    "res": "login with wrong userid"
  }
  ....
]
```

The above response will always have values for `resType` and `res` but there can be any number of such entries.

For every set of `Hostnames` within `data` object I want to call `fetchHostDetails(hostnames)`, and want to replace `Hostnames` with the response value in the original `data` object

Desired response:

```
{
  "error1": {
    "7": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
        "result": [
          {
            "resType": "unknow data",
            "res": "missing data"
          },
          {
            "resType": "login failed",
            "res": "login with wrong userid"
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "8": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
        "result": [
          {
            "resType": "new data",
            "res": "data"
          },
          {
            "resType": "data failed",
            "res": "invalid"
          },          {
            "resType": "res failed",
            "res": "discard"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1C",
        "result": [
          {
            "resType": "sample data",
            "res": "sample"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  "error2": {
    "3": [
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
        "result": [
          {
            "resType": "Mydata",
            "res": "Mydata is empty"
          }
        ]
      },
    ...
  },
  "error3": {
    "1": [
     ...
    ]
  }
}
```

So far I have written the following code

```
const hostNames = [];
        for (let key in data) {
            for (let number in data[key]) {
                data[key][number].map( d=> {
                    hostNames.push(d.Hostnames);
                });
            }
        }

`hostNames` array looks as below:
[
  "host123.com,hostabc.com,host33a.com...",
  "host223.com,host2c.com,host43a.com...",
  "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com...",
  "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com...",
...
]
```

Now, I need to call `await fetchHostDetails(hostnames)` for each value within `hostNames`.
I also need to embed the response within `data` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll need each host name split out of each string in that array. Once you do that, you'll be able to place them all in a single array (`flat()`) and then loop through them to call `fetchHostDetails(hostname)`.

Please read the comments in the code. This code will output each URL in the console as if it has been passed to your fetch function.

```js
const data = {
  "error1": {
    "7": [{
      "ErrorType": "Error-1A",
      "Hostnames": "host123.com,hostabc.com,host33a.com..."
    }],
    "8": [{
        "ErrorType": "Error-1B",
        "Hostnames": "host223.com,host2c.com,host43a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-1C",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ]
  },
  "error2": {
    "3": [{
        "ErrorType": "Error-2A",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2B",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ],
    "8": [{
        "ErrorType": "Error-2C",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-2D",
        "Hostnames": "host1231.com,host2abc.com,host313a.com..."
      }
    ]
  },
  "error3": {
    "1": [{
        "ErrorType": "Error-3A",
        "Hostnames": "host1236.com"
      },
      {
        "ErrorType": "Error-3B",
        "Hostnames": "hostc3231.com"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const out = [];
for (let key in data) {
  for (let number in data[key]) {
    data[key][number].map(d => out.push(d.Hostnames));
  }
}

out.flat().map(async urlList => {
  const responseArr = await fetchStuff(urlList);
  console.log(responseArr);
});

async function fetchStuff(urlList) {
  return urlList;
}
```

Comment: I am doing `responseArr.push(response);` but `responseArr` is having an empty value.

Comment: I don't require splitting each hostname as I am taking care of it in my my `fetchStuff` function. Can you please suggest why `responseArr` is coming as empty?

Comment: I edited the code/answer. See if that answers your question.

Comment: Okay let me check it. One more thing, after the `console.log(responseArr);` I basically need to embed `responseArr` to `data` object as shown in my desired output. Appreciate your help on it!